# Cropped Data (Text) with List Boxes and Dropdown in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am in a strange problem where the row-data entry size is larger than the width of my dropdown and list box. When this happens, the text is being cut-short.

Some of the examples of this being happening is:-

[image: Notice the End of text being truncated]
[image: Notice the End of text being truncated]
[image: This hides all the text when dropdown is clicked.]

### Code

The Code is as follows:-

### Dropdown

```
<div class="level select">
    <select id="MainContent_cmbClientName" style="width:140px;">

        <option selected="selected" value="Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight">Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight</option>
        <option value="Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight">Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight</option>
        <option value="Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight">Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight</option>
        <option value="Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight">Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight</option>
        <option value="Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight">Select One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

### Select Box

```
<select size="4" id="MainContent_lstFamilyStatus" class="client-bg-repeat" style="color:#000060;">


    <option value="1">Couple</option>
      <option value="2">Family with 2+ Children</option>
      <option value="3">Family with One Child</option>
      <option value="4">Single Female</option>
    <option value="5">Single Female and not willing to marry</option>

</select>
```

Is there any way I can fix this problem or may be bring the text to the next line which is being cut due to text overflow.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Found Solutions for Dropdown

```
<style>
.ctrDropDown{
    width:145px;
    font-size:11px;
}
.ctrDropDownClick{
    font-size:11px;

    width:300px;

}
.plainDropDown{
    width:145px;
    font-size:11px;
}
</style>


<select name="someDropDown" id="someDropDown" class="ctrDropDown" onBlur="this.className='ctrDropDown';" onMouseDown="this.className='ctrDropDownClick';" onChange="this.className='ctrDropDown';">
    <option value="">This is option 1.</option>
    <option value="">This is the second option, a bit longer.</option>
    <option value="">Drink to me only with thine eyes, and I will pledge with mine...</option>
</select>
```

It works (Thanks to Doug Boud).

### Any Idea, how I can fix the select box and bring the overflown text to the next line?

Thanks.